# Android Deep link from Play Store using branch.io

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io

I am using branch.io for integrating the deep linking in my Android App.

If the app was installed on device, it will redirect to an app along with parameter(Deep Link Data).

If the app was not installed on device, it will redirect to the Playstore page correctly. But after install the app and open it, the parameter wasn't sent into the app.

My question is how can I pass the parameter through the Playstore or is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: yes, this is definitely possible! It's called 'deferred deep linking', and in fact it's one of our main features. Any data you attach to the link when it is created will be retrievable inside the app.

See [this guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/overview/) for more into on how to set it up.